# List of Fonts Provided by Application (iOS)

Tags: ios, xcode, fonts, info.plist

does anyone know how to get a list of custom fonts from the 'Fonts provided by application' key in the info.plist file in Xcode?
Thanks

Comment: Is your question how to read the Info.plist entry (which is a list of font *file names*)? Or do you need the *font names* (which can be different from the file name?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following code reads the list of custom font files from the Info.plist,
and extracts the full font name from the font file.
(Parts of the code is copied from https://stackoverflow.com/a/17519740/1187415
with small modifications and ARC adjustments).

Objective-C

```
NSDictionary* infoDict = [[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary];
NSArray* fontFiles = [infoDict objectForKey:@"UIAppFonts"];

for (NSString *fontFile in fontFiles) {
    NSLog(@"file name: %@", fontFile);
    NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:fontFile withExtension:NULL];
    NSData *fontData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    CGDataProviderRef fontDataProvider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData((__bridge CFDataRef)fontData);
    CGFontRef loadedFont = CGFontCreateWithDataProvider(fontDataProvider);
    NSString *fullName = CFBridgingRelease(CGFontCopyFullName(loadedFont));
    CGFontRelease(loadedFont);
    CGDataProviderRelease(fontDataProvider);
    NSLog(@"font name: %@", fullName);
}
```

Swift 3 equivalent:

```
if let infoDict = Bundle.main.infoDictionary,
    let fontFiles = infoDict["UIAppFonts"] as? [String] {
    for fontFile in fontFiles {
        print("file name", fontFile)
        if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: fontFile, withExtension: nil),
            let fontData = NSData(contentsOf: url), 
            let fontDataProvider = CGDataProvider(data: fontData) {
            let loadedFont = CGFont(fontDataProvider)
            if let fullName = loadedFont.fullName {
                print("font name", fullName)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wonderful! Very smart. This list the fonts in a smart way, instead of the lazy UIFonts that can't be used by Mac developers. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can add your costume font http://www.danielhanly.com/blog/tutorial/including-custom-fonts-in-ios/
[image]
But, I don't, know how to get this list, sorry.
But, may be you can look on it in IB, in UILabel attributes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know about this but i'm hoping to get an array of the font names stored in this field. Do you know any way to do this?

Comment: No,I don't know any quick solution for it. But I can offer you, copy from this page (http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5484) font names, add them to .txt file, add this file to project, and parse it with NSString methods and add in cycle to Array.
If you interesting for it, ask about in other question (its different write code in comments)