# How can I get the font names bundled in my iOS app?

Tags: ios

I have added some custom true type fonts in my iOS app from Xcode app-info.plist (using the key "Fonts provided by application").

iOS automatically recognized them as available fonts in the app and I can get the names of all font families including iOS-provided system fonts using [UIFont familyNames].

But I want to know which fonts are from iOS system fonts and which fonts are from the custom fonts I added in the bundle.

Is there any programmatic way to differentiate bundled fonts from system fonts or just a way to get all bundled font names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is blatently ripped off from [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18298713/list-of-fonts-provided-by-application-ios)
It should provide you with all the font names from your bundled fonts.

```
NSDictionary* infoDict = [[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary];
NSArray* fontFiles = [infoDict objectForKey:@"UIAppFonts"];

for (NSString *fontFile in fontFiles) {
    NSLog(@"file name: %@", fontFile);
    NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:fontFile withExtension:NULL];
    NSData *fontData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    CGDataProviderRef fontDataProvider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData((__bridge CFDataRef)fontData);
    CGFontRef loadedFont = CGFontCreateWithDataProvider(fontDataProvider);
    NSString *fullName = CFBridgingRelease(CGFontCopyFullName(loadedFont));
    CGFontRelease(loadedFont);
    CGDataProviderRelease(fontDataProvider);
    NSLog(@"font name: %@", fullName);
}
```

This answer would get you the proper font name, but if you're just wanting the font name from the info plist:

```
NSDictionary* infoDict = [[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary];
NSArray *arrayOfFontStringNames = infoDict[@"UIAppFonts"];
```

Comment: Thanks but should I actually re-create the fonts from bundled files just to get the names? Is there any more efficient ways in case I have a lot of them?

Comment: Simplification would to be just get the array of the font names.

Comment: The suggested simplification would not retrieve the font names but the font file names. But I would accept the original answer since it looks like there's no other way currently.

Comment: It turned out that I actually needed to use CGFontCopyPostScriptName instead of CGFontCopyFullName to retrieve the font names that match the return value of [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:]